# ctypes: How to access array of structure returned by function?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a c++ API functions which I need to call from python using ctypes.
In my c++ `libamo.h`, I have prototypes for `struct` and `function` as below,

```
typedef struct contain_t
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t ele1;
    uint16_t ele2;
    uint16_t ele3;
    uint16_t ele4;
    float ele5;
} mycontain;
```

```
mycontain* get_result(void *context, int r, int c, unsigned char* rawdata);
```

In my c++ `libamo.cpp`,
I have declared global array of struct,

```
mycontain all_contain[50];
```

and the function `mycontain* get_result()` populates array of struct, which I have tested in c++ by printing the contents of struct.

In `ctypes`:

- am loading the `libamo.so`.
- defined the structure template as,

```
from ctypes import *
class mycontain(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('id', c_uint),
                ('ele1',c_uint),
                ('ele2', c_uint),
                ('ele3', c_uint),
                ('ele4', c_uint), 
                ('ele5', c_float) ]

ptr_cnt = POINTER(mycontain)
amo_get_result = libamo.get_result
amo_get_result.restype = ptr_cnt
amo_get_result.argtypeps = [c_void_p, c_int, c_int, c_char_p]

res = amo_get_result(amo_context, 300, 300, raw_val.ctypes.data_as(c_char_p))
```

***I tried following method to get the data from member of struct.***
**Method 1:**

```
output_res = res.contents
print(output_res.id, output_res.ele1, output_res.ele2, output_res.ele3, output_res.ele4, output_res.ele5)
```

at output I get, for above elements

```
7208960 0.0 4128919 173 1049669215 21364736
```

**Method 2: Tried casting**

```
print(cast(output_res.id, POINTER(c_uint)))

output>><__main__.LP_c_uint object at 0x7f9450f3c0>
```

*My question is,*
***- How to elegantly read data from array of struct.*** I have refereed multiple SO posts, most discusses ways to access single instance of struct, not array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the matching types in the struct.  `c_uint` is typically 32-bit so your Python structure has the wrong size.

To access the array, index the pointer (e.g. `output_res[0].id`) or use slicing.

Here's a reproducible example with a test DLL:

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct contain_t
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t ele1;
    uint16_t ele2;
    uint16_t ele3;
    uint16_t ele4;
    float ele5;
} mycontain;

mycontain all_contain[5];

extern "C"
API mycontain* get_result(void *context, int r, int c, unsigned char* rawdata) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        all_contain[i].id = i;
        all_contain[i].ele1 = i*2;
        all_contain[i].ele2 = i*3;
        all_contain[i].ele3 = i*4;
        all_contain[i].ele4 = i*5;
        all_contain[i].ele5 = i * 1.01;
    }
    return all_contain;
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

class mycontain(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('id', c_uint8),    # use correct types
                ('ele1',c_uint16),
                ('ele2', c_uint16),
                ('ele3', c_uint16),
                ('ele4', c_uint16), 
                ('ele5', c_float) ]

    # Make a display representation for easy viewing
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'mycontain(id={self.id}, ele1={self.ele1}, ..., ele5={self.ele5:.2f})'

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.get_result.argtypes = c_void_p, c_int, c_int, c_char_p
dll.get_result.restype = POINTER(mycontain)

res = dll.get_result(None, 300, 300, None)
print(res[:5])  # slice to appropriate size to get list of elements
```

Output:

```py
[mycontain(id=0, ele1=0, ..., ele5=0.00), mycontain(id=1, ele1=2, ..., ele5=1.01), mycontain(id=2, ele1=4, ..., ele5=2.02), mycontain(id=3, ele1=6, ..., ele5=3.03), mycontain(id=4, ele1=8, ..., ele5=4.04)]
```

Comment: Hey @mark.. Thanks a lot for the solution... This worked... I was stuck for so many days. You saved me a day.